# Be Nice. People are coming here for help, don't insult them or their hardware

Tags: discussion

When a user with old hardware comes here to ask a question, it isn't appropriate to insult their old hardware. Comments like this are off putting:

> Your PC is a dinosaur, and your graphics card is an etch-a-sketch. [...]

or

> You're joking right? Your PC's graphics card is a joke. So is your RAM and CPU, in fact. Get an actual computer. [...]

---

Regardless of the question being on topic or not, we need to [treat other members with respect](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). They are here to get help, not to be berated on their current hardware.

> **Rudeness and belittling language are not okay.** Your tone should match the way you'd talk in person with someone you respect and whom you want to respect you. *If you don't have time to say something politely, just leave it for someone who does.*

Both of the comments excerpted above contain information that is helpful - after the users got their cheap shots in. The other information is helpful. The rudeness is not.

We want to help users, not drive them away. Be aware of what you are writing to others.

Comment: If you're going looking for the comments quoted here, I've just removed them so you won't find much. This post is spot-on.

Comment: I agree completely.  I do sometimes get a bit annoyed when people post questions that could obviously be solved by a google search, or newegg search, and may point that out.  But I still help them out.  But I never have/will never bash someones hardware.    I've been in the boat of having aging equipment.  And just because you can shell out over 1k for the newest GPU, really doesn't make someone all that special........

Comment: @Andy Be Nice should apply to both the OP and those responding.  As in someone asks recommendations for a certain device, but gives asinine requirements.  Someone answers with what appears to most closely match the requirement, but OP more or less tells responder to "work harder" at finding the perfect match.  Just as peoples hardware should be respected, the time/effort someone puts into research into an answer should be respected as well.  Or am I wrong on this one?

Comment: You are not wrong. Both sides need to respect one another. As an answerer, you have the added benefit of being able to completely ignore requests demanding you utilize more of your time to answer such requests.